# jQuery Mobile Beta: can no longer use $('[data-role=header]')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I used to be able to get hold of

```
$('[data-role=header]').first().height()
```

in alpha with jQuery 1.5.2, but no longer can in beta with jQuery 1.6.1. Has something changed?

Full code - this writes 0 to console.log...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head> 
 <title>Page Title</title> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 console.log($('[data-role=header]').first().height());
 });
 </script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="home">

       <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Header</h1>
       </div>
 <div data-role="content">
         //lots of code
        </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, change this to jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery Mobile alpha:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

and it writes the non-zero height of the header div.

Incidentally, it is also non-zero with jQuery 1.6.1 but without jQuery Mobile. So it's something to do with the jQuery Mobile rendering.

Can't see anything in the [release notes](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/) to suggest what might have happened, but I'm no jQuery expert.

Comment: what does it write in Alpha/Beta, or what did you expect it to write?

Comment: In alpha it writes something non-zero, because the div has a non-zero height. In beta it's zero. Incidentally with jQuery 1.6.1 but *without* jQuery Mobile it's also non-zero (have edited question to reflect this).

Comment: Could you try this: $('[data-role="header"]').first().height()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they did change some of the syntax, Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/methods.html

> When finding elements by their jQuery
>   Mobile data attribute, please use the
>   custom selector :jqmData(), as it
>   automatically incorporates namespaced
>   data attributes into the lookup when
>   they are in use. For example, instead
>   of calling $("div[data-role='page']"),
>   you should use
>   $("div:jqmData(role='page')"), which
>   internally maps to $("div[data-"+
>   $.mobile.ns +"role='page']") without
>   forcing you to concatenate a namespace
>   into your selectors manually.

Try this:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='header')").first().height()
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The change that is causing the difference is "Responsive design helper classes: Now deprecated"</strike>

> We include a set of [responsive design helper classes](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/mediahelpers.html) designed to make it easy to build a responsive design that adapts the layout for various screen widths. At the time, we went with a system of dynamically appended min- and max-width classes on the body that are updated on load, resize and orientation change events as a workaround for the limitation that Internet Explorer doesn’t support media queries.

Basically, the page is getting `min-height` set to the current page height in the beta which is overriding the `.landscape { min-height: 300px; }` in the alpha.

It looks like you need to use [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) if you want a page layout that changes or you could just add CSS `style="height:43px"` on the the header if you need a fixed height.

Seems like the page is not ready when you query the `height()`. [There is no `document.ready` for jQuery.mobile](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/). It doesn't explain why there is a difference between alpha and beta, but I guess a code path changed that exposed the issue.

Wrapping the query in a different event, returns the height as expected.

```
$("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pageshow',function(){
    console.log($('[data-role=header]').first().height());
});
```

I found this by examining the offsetHeight of the DOM element in the Chrome console which was non-zero but, as you reported, the `height()` was always reporting 0. I then created an link when clicked output the height and it was non-zero. I then realised that the `height()` was being called before the page was fully ready.

Relevant - [jQuery mobile $(document).ready equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622581/jquery-mobile-document-ready-equivalent)