# What's the right way to do $(document).ready in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, document-ready

Suppose I want to run some code once jQuery Mobile has finished rendering the UI. The `mobileinit` event doesn't work since it's raised *before* this happens. A quick Google search seems to indicate that simply using `$(document).ready` won't work with JQM; but I just tried it (called after `mobileinit`) and it worked for me: my code ran and dynamically updated elements, etc. just fine. So I'm wondering, is there some reason I *shouldn't* be using it (it's unreliable or messes up JQM), or is the information out there about it not working simply inaccurate? What am I missing?

**Update**: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ec7YR/1/) for a demonstration.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622581/jquery-mobile-document-ready-equivalent ?

Comment: @George: Yes, and according to that question `$(document).ready` *doesn't* work. But strangely, for me, it does. So I guess I'm just trying to figure out if it just works now, or if there are some weird gotchas when dealing with JQM that I should know about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely the reason you read that $(document).ready won't work with jQuery Mobile is that it does not fire each time you view a pseudo-page. That said, it still triggers as it should when the html document is loaded.

If you want to run code that triggers each time you view a pseudo-page you can use this code:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () {
    //run your code here
});
```

NOTE: there are other hooks that you can bind to as well (pageshow, pagehide, pagebefoershow, pagebeforehide), documentation can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html

**---------- EDIT ----------**

I was thinking about this and the best analog to $(document).ready() is not binding to the "pageshow" event, it would be binding to the "pagecreate" event. $(document).ready() fires once per page load, and "pagecreate" does the same for pseudo-pages whereas "pageshow" fires each time a page is displayed.

So if a user clicked away from the home-screen and then clicked a back button to return to the home-screen, "pageshow" would fire on this second (and subsequent) "showing" of the home-screen.

Also, "pageshow" requires the user to navigate to the page to which it is bound.

Comment: Ah, I see; so the idea that it "doesn't work" was all along based on a misunderstanding? It's funny; I saw these alternative approaches and thought they were *less than ideal* because they caused an event to fire before each pseudo-page is shown rather than just once for the entire document (i.e., jQuery mobile site). Whereas the latter is precisely what I want.

Comment: @jasper you're linking to the alpha version api events, best to use beta version