# Web service not called the second time if i make a request to webserver

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application made by using phonegap 1.5.0 and jquery mobile 1.1.0....
I have a structure like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">       
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">       
</div>
```

I call a webservice on page show of the page2 like this

```
$("#page2").on("pageshow", function(e) {
$
    .ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "http://192.168.1.88:9051/some.xml"
                + "?time=" + Date.now(),
        data : {
            key : "value"
        },
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(xml) {

        },

        error : function(xhr) {
            alert("Error while loading the Mock Service !!!");
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine if i enter for the first time to Page2. Suppose if i navigate back to page1 and then again to Page2 then the webservice isnt called.

I even tried with pageinit and it didnt worked... Is this some Ajax issue?

How to rectify this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622581/jquery-mobile-document-ready-equivalent asks to use pagebeforeshow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried turning off caching?

```
// setup globally
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

Or,

```
// setup individual calls
$.ajax({
    cache: false, // disable caching
    type : 'GET',
    url : "http://192.168.1.88:9051/some.xml"
            + "?time=" + Date.now(),
    data : { key : "value"},
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(xml) {

    },

    error : function(xhr) {
        alert("Error while loading the Mock Service !!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can declare it anywhere within your $(function(){});

Comment: It isnt working still... Is there a way that we can remove the page if we hide it?

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Something is not right there.

Comment: Hi Dennis... It seems like i can only make 3 Webservice Ajax calls only in the entire document... I tested it in many Scenarios... What might be the reason?

Comment: Have you figured out if this is a web service or a client-side AJAX issue?

Answer (score 0):

did you check with firebug, the "Console" and the "Net" tab to see what your script sends and receives?

```
$("#div")
```

looks wrong to me. should be either `div` (all div elemets) or `#page1` (id 'page1')