# Jquery document.ready not triggered without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, document-ready

I'm facing this very weird issue that my function in document ready is not triggered, unless I put `alert` after the function. I found this out when I debug using the `alert`, and apparently everything was working fine. But when I removed the `alert`, function 'RaiseEvent' never get called.

Here's my HTML:

```
<script src="../Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/hybrid.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            //populate form
            //alert('Calling POPULATE-FORM');
            RaiseEvent('POPULATE-FORM');
            //alert('After POPULATE-FORM');
});
</script>
```

The `RaiseEvent function` is retrieved from hybrid.js:

```
function RaiseEvent(eventName)
{
    if (!eventName) eventName = '';
    var qs = '';
    var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        if (elms[i].name) {
            qs += (qs.length > 0 ? '&' : '') + encodeURIComponent(elms[i].name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(elms[i].value);
        }
        if (elms[i].type == 'checkbox' && elms[i].checked)
            qs += (qs.length > 0 ? '&' : '') +
            'checked:' + encodeURIComponent(elms[i].name) + '=1';
    }
    location.href = 'xpostback:' + eventName + ':' + qs;
}
```

I've googled this issue and found few people facing this also [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1939326.aspx?document%20ready%20not%20fired%20except%20with%20alerts%20in%20it) but I followed his solution already to no avail.

Anyone facing the same issue or have any suggestions/advice what might go wrong?

Comment: What does `RaiseEvent` do? There might be some asynchronous behavior and it "works" with `alert` because `alert` is blocking.

Comment: all the jquery files and the javascript at the same place?

Comment: what is `RaiseEvent` do and how are you checking whether it is getting called

Comment: It can happen because javascript is asynchronous. But here it have to be something about your overall code structure, including imports.

Comment: @cracker yes they are

Comment: @FelixKling it does a postback that will be handled later to call a C# function. the whole system is much more complex than this, bcos I'm creating an iOS app with C# and Webview as Frontend. But anyway I'm interested in ur saying, async behavior and alert is blocking. what do u mean by that?

Comment: If you put an alert at the beginning of `RaiseEvent`, does it appear?

Comment: @Barmar if I put the alert only before the RaiseEvent, the function RaiseEvent never get called. But if I put another alert at the end, it is called.

Comment: whether some of the page elements are created dynamically...

Comment: I asked what happens if you put the alert inside `RaiseEvent`.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @ArunPJohny bcause the RaiseEvent initialize the content dynamically in my page, so if it gets called, everything gets initialized correctly. But if it's never called, the loading dialog never dismisses

Comment: @yonasstephen put that RaiseEvent before </script> tag and remove the Scripts/hybrid.js it will work sure

Comment: @Barmar oh! thanks now I just noticed different problem, it is actually get called! but I think the function inside is skipped, now I can narrow down my debugging

Comment: What is the `xpostback:` URI scheme supposed to do? I can't find any information about that.

Comment: @Barmar that's basically a naming I made myself. the location.href will throw an error and pass the xpostback string to a method to process. this method will determine which C# method to handle the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is another "document.ready" function in hybrid.js that caused inconsistent RaiseEvent calling. Probably because the asynchronous nature of Javascript, the RaiseEvent('POPULATE-FORM') get overlapped by the RaiseEvent('DOCUMENT-READY') in hybrid.js:

```
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        RaiseEvent("DOCUMENT_READY");
        Init();
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
    }
}, 50);
```

Credits to @Barmar for helping me debugging the isssue!

Answer (score 1):

I have some thoughts on your problem.

#### a) Callback function in ready()

From documentation `handler` is callback function which means that when DOM element is ready your function is beeing called. I suppose that is not the problem.

```
document.ready( handler );
```

#### b) Jquery.mobile

Fast googling told me that you could use different function. See [pagecreated](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/) documentation.

```
 $(document).on('pagecreated',function(){ 
                RaiseEvent('POPULATE-FORM');
            });
```

Also look here:

1. [jQuery mobile $(document).ready equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622581/jquery-mobile-document-ready-equivalent)
2. [jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events)

#### c) Error in function RaiseEvent(eventName)

Even if your function works with `alert` this doesn't guarantee that you function is working properly. I had a lot of situations that in all modern browsers my code works but there was some bugs. Only `Internet Explorer` was so kind and throw me errors. I suggest running your code with JS debugger.

#### Summary

I would start from `b)` and then try to look at `c)`. Good luck :)